# Prove the time complexity of a Tree Traversal Algorithm for a general tree

Tags: algorithm, math, tree, big-o, time-complexity

I'm looking for a way to prove the run time of the pre-tree traversal algorithm for a n-ary tree.

Each node can have any number of children.

I seem to be only able to find a proof for a binary tree.

I understand intuitively that the run time will be O(n) but am confused as to how to come up with a rigorous proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work done at a node v in a preorder traversal is O(1 + c_v), where c_v is the number of children of node v. This is because we do some constant amount of work, then visit each child exactly once.

Summing this up over all nodes gives O(n) plus the sum of O(c_v) over all nodes v. That quantity is O(n), since summing across the number of children of each tree node is equivalent to summing over all nodes but the root (do you see why?)

Overall, the runtime is O(n).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I understand that the time is O(n), after all the purpose of the algorithm is to visit each node once.  I am wondering if there is a more formal method of proving it however.

Comment: I thought this was formal enough - if a student turned this in in an algorithms class, I'd give it full credit. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I just thought of trying to prove it myself and then found this post, so I'll share what I have as it seems to prove it.

The proof is for the recursive DFS of a binary tree (in-order or pre-order or post-order), assuming it is perfectly balanced.

My notation might not be perfect, but it should give the gist.

[image]

It starts by using the recurrence relationship saying that the time to visit all nodes is equal to a constant time `c` to visit the root + the time to visit all nodes of the left subtree, `T((n-1)/2)` + the time to visit all the nodes of the right subtree `T((n-1)/2)`. And we know that visiting a tree of one node only takes constant time `T(1)=c`.

```
T(n) = 2T((n-1)/2) + c
T(1) = 1
```

By doing a few iterations of the recursion, we notice a pattern and use `k` to show this relationship. Because we know the base-case `T(1)=c` we solve for `k` (in green). This essentially tells us how many times we need to traverse another level (depth).
Substituting `k` back into our equation, everything cancels out nicely and we get `T(n)=O(n)`.